# .net: how to evaluate this error

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, database-connection, connection-string

I am new to vb.net and I am trying to create a login form but on running this code i get error `msg("ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.")`

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim da As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sdr As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dbprovider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OleDb.4.0;"
        Dim dbsource As String = "Data Source=C:\Users\RAJKRI\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Banking System.mdb"
        con.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\RAJKRI\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Banking System.accdb")

        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Empid = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "' , con")
        sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If (sdr.Read() = True) Then
        Form2.Show()
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""

        Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Employee Id/Password")

        End If
    End Sub

     Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You are appending your connection object to your query as text. Change

```
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Empid = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "' , con")
```

to

```
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Empid = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'" , con)
```

(the difference is at the end)